# DBT run erros when on certain schemas

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I'm using dbt over a VPN connection to deploy models in snowflake. I have a schema called trans where I deploy my views. These run fine without issue. However, when I try to run an incremental model in another schema.
This fails with the error:

```
OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'
```

Comment: This means you have a proxy in between that requires authentication. DBT uses Snowflake Python connector and the connector supports a [proxy](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#using-a-proxy-server) and I see in DBT code that you can set it via [proxy_host/proxy_port](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/blob/d3589a9d1f1ca89c7a924f73070e150b3a0587b8/dbt/adapters/snowflake/connections.py#L77)

Comment: I have the proxy enabled. I also authenticate my Snowflake credentials via SSO.

Comment: Since it looks like a proxy that requires authentication, how did you enabled it? Does it looks like this in the variable: `username:password@proxyserver.company.com:80` ?